# Use HL7-FHIR standard in Golang

Tags: go, hl7-fhir

Is there a suitable package to be able to use the FHIR standard in Golang? There should be a small dependency on the Google Cloud.

Comment: You might find http://community.fhir.org/ more useful for this question. I see https://github.com/intervention-engine/fhir but it is not actively developed.

Answer (score 1):

One way of using FHIR in Golang is the FHIR Protocol Buffers implementation: https://github.com/google/fhir

This includes a Golang parser/serializer for JSON to protobuf, which will get you language-specific data structures. It doesn't include a library for the FHIR REST API but you can use standard http libraries for that.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "It doesn't include a library for the FHIR REST API but you can use standard http libraries for that." please?

Comment: Ultimately, FHIR rest operations are pretty much basic HTTP.  For example, to search for FHIR patients, you just do something like:

```
GET /fhir/r4/Patient?family=smith&given=john
```

All of this is fully documented at https://www.hl7.org/fhir/http.html.

The only big thing to know is that you can get a "CapabilityStatement" defining what the server offers by calling "/metadata".  Also, most servers will return either XML or JSON depending on what you put in the `Accepts` header